# Как правильно считать сумму товара в корзине используя ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Товар приходит массивом и потом через форыч вывожу.
Сумма товара в корзине:
`$sum += $value->cart_amount * $value->price`
Удаляю 1 товар с корзины используя ajax, а общая сумма остается прежней.(меняется только если перезагрузить страницу)
Сумму нужно как то через ajax считать? а потом выводить? Подскажите или дайте какой то пример.

Answer (score 0):

Сделай Api метод на PHP, который изменит значение в БД, а потом вернет новое значение в ответе на запрос.

Код на JS будет выглядеть примерно так:

`$http.post('calc-sum', { goods }).then(result => {
 document.querySelector('#cost-block').innerHTML = result.sum; 
})`

То есть после отработки запросы ты вставляешь в DOM новое значение суммы на основе отправленных товаров.

Comment: Сумма не записывается в бд. Просто считает то, что в корзине.

Comment: @Andrii ну так не важно, ты просто верни в теле ответа сумму и все.

Comment: Не пойму как мне `$sum += $value->cart_amount * $value->price` передать в Ajax data эту переменную для обработки